# Merge lists inside the list in python

Tags: python, list

Using Python I want to convert:

```
outputlist = []

list = [[1,2,3],[a,b,c],[p,q,r]]
outputlist =[[1,a,p],[2,b,q],[3,c,r]]
```

How do I do this?

```
outputlist.append([li [0] for li in list ])
```

it yields

```
[1,a,p]
```

not the other items. I need it for all of the items.

Comment: Are you constrained to use a one-line instruction?

Answer (score 6):

You want to use `zip`:

**Code:**

```
lst = [[1,2,3],['a','b','c'],['p','q','r']]

print(zip(*lst))
```

**Results:**

```
[(1, 'a', 'p'), (2, 'b', 'q'), (3, 'c', 'r')]
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen.It works

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = [ [1,2,3],['a','b','c'],['p','q','r']]
>>> np.array(l).T.tolist()
[['1', 'a', 'p'], ['2', 'b', 'q'], ['3', 'c', 'r']]
```

Comment: Thanks shizhz.It works

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [[1,2,3],[a,b,c],[p,q,r]]
outputlist = zip(*list)
```

`zip()` returns the elements as tuples, covert them to lists if that's exactly what you require.